# Google Maps API Encryption

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-maps-api-3

So this is my first time programming with Google's API, and Stack Overflow has been very resourceful, but before I get started, I have a requirement that must be met.

First, the API will be passed two addresses. From there, I will need the distance between these two points. This shouldn't be a problem.

The question is, can I pass these addresses encrypted/encoded? Meaning, I don't want to pass "123 Main St.", I want to pass a scrambled string so that the address cannot be read in the page source or any packet sniffer.

Does the Google Maps API support something like this (maybe a code behind), or are there any workarounds/suggestions on how to accomplish this requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely use the Google Maps API from code-behind and I have used it in several projects. Beware that you may need to have some points opened for your server if you use the API via server-side code, this restriction does not exist on the client-side.

As of 2011, Google requires all Google Maps API requests to use https, so you will get some data protection that way.

Check out [Google Maps API V3 for ASP.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/291499/Google-Maps-API-V3-for-ASP-NET) for a quick run-through of using the Google Maps APi both with JavaScript and code-behind (C#).

Comment: Awesome sauce! Ports shouldn't be that big of an issue, we're just worried that addresses will 'leak' out via the API or its calls.